# Start activity not starting

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My activity start intent works with other activities but I can't get it to work on this particular one (PostActivity.java).
 Here are the following classes:

PostActivity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.MainActivities.BottomActivity;
import com.example.shrinkio.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton video;
    StorageTask uploadTask;
    EditText Post;
     Uri imageUri;
     String myUrl = "";
     ImageView close;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    TextView post;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout_post);

        Post = findViewById(R.id.Post);

        close = findViewById(R.id.close);
        post = findViewById(R.id.post);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("post");


        close.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, BottomActivity.class)));
        finish();

        post.setOnClickListener(view -> uploadImage());


        video = findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
        video.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

        });


    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.post_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.menu.post_menu){

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("post").push();

                String post = Post.getText().toString();


                startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, BottomActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Shrinked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);


                video.setImageURI(imageUri);

                DatabaseReference nPost = databaseReference.push();
                nPost.child("post").setValue(post);
                nPost.child("img").setValue(imageUri);

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    //Post




    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

        }


        private void uploadImage(){
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Posting...");

            if (imageUri != null) {
                StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
                uploadTask = filereference.putFile(imageUri);

                uploadTask.continueWithTask((Continuation) task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                    }

                    return filereference;
                })
                        .addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<Uri>) task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                        String postId = reference.push().getKey();

                        HashMap<String , Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("postId", post);
                            hashMap.put("post_image", myUrl);
                            hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            reference.child(postId).setValue(hashMap);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, BottomActivity.class));
                            finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }                    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

            }  else {
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, " No Image Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            assert result != null;
            imageUri  = result.getUri();
            video.setImageURI(imageUri);
            video.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BottomActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the activity that intents the PostActivity.java

BottomActivity.java:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.MessagesFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.NotFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.Fragments.PeopleFragment;
import com.example.shrinkio.R;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.PostActivity;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.Posts;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.ProfileActivity;
import com.example.shrinkio.SecondaryActivities.SettingsActivity;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;

import static com.example.shrinkio.R.menu.main_menu;


public class BottomActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



    RecyclerView rv;
    TextView post_desc;
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private static final String TAG = "";
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

    @SuppressLint({"RtlHardcoded", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MultiDex.install(this);
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_bottom );
        new GestureOverlayView( this );

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout_home);




        //Action bar configurations


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit() ;

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation1);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


        rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        post_desc = findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        String user_id = firebaseUser.getUid();
        myRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(user_id).child("post");






    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_post:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if ( fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
        return loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Query query = myRef.child("post");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                .setQuery(query, Posts.class)
                .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Posts, PostViewHolder> (
                options)
        {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position, Posts model) {
                holder.setPost(model.getPost());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts, parent, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(view);

            }
        };


        rv.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();




    }
    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mView;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setPost(String post) {
            TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_title.setText(post);
            Log.d(TAG, "It works");
        }
    }







    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    selectedFragment = new NotFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_people:
                    selectedFragment = new PeopleFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_messages:
                    selectedFragment = new MessagesFragment();
            }

            if (selectedFragment != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();
            }
            return true;
    }

    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                selectedFragment = new NotFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_people:
                selectedFragment = new PeopleFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_messages:
                selectedFragment = new MessagesFragment();
        }

        if (selectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    selectedFragment).commit();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I am calling the intent on the menu item click, but nothing happens, no error is displayed on the logcat, however, with other activities it works like a charm.

I have tried every question on StackOverflow but none seems to work, any help is aprecciated.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the same Intent to any other view in activity (a button for example)

Comment: Yes, it also doesn’t work, but with other activities it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `finish()` is the case? Your `PostActivity` in `onCreate()` contains `finish()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout_post);

    Post = findViewById(R.id.Post);

    close = findViewById(R.id.close);
    post = findViewById(R.id.post);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("post");

    close.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, BottomActivity.class)));
    // TODO remove this one
    finish();

    post.setOnClickListener(view -> uploadImage());


    video = findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
    video.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

    });
}
```